# Boundary points of a manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm reading about Riemannian Geometry and my question is regarding Manifolds with Boundary.

I want to show a point of a manifold with boundary is either an interior point or a boundary point, so no overlap.

Let $\mathbb{H}_n$ be the closed half space of dimension n. 
In order to prove the above my aim is to show an open neighborhood U of a point p, in $\mathbb{H}_n$\ $\partial \mathbb{H}_n$ can't be homeomorphic to an open subset U of $\mathbb{H}_n$ when we identify p with a point in $\partial \mathbb{H}_n$.

How should I proceed?

Comment: You should proceed to find some property that one of the has and the other does not.

Comment: Right, but I'm having difficulty finding a mutually exclusive event.

Comment: Think about the topology on $\mathbb{H}^n$, and how it relates to the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Also, you should prove that "being on the boundary" is a property independent of choice of local coordinates --- the inverse function theorem is useful.

Comment: That last part I think I can handle. Can you show me how to answer my original question? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this thread mentions in the comments,

[Interior and boundary points of $n$-manifold with boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74038/interior-and-boundary-points-of-n-manifold-with-boundary)

you need the "invariance of domain" theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

to prove what you want, which is nontrivial, and requires the use of algebraic topology. As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a much simpler proof that's easily accessible.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!